# How to properly perform a GET request with HttpClientModule

Tags: json, angular, typescript, get, httprequest

Im having issues with performing a simple get request to the backend which returns a JSON. When i perform this get request in my code it returns an observable, which i directly assign to a variable through the subscribe method. However it is only assinged and available within this method and undefined everywhere else.

The api service get method:

```
public getAllProcessCategories() {
     return this.http.get(this.apiURL + 'typeOne=PROCESSCATEGORIES&typeTwo=PROCESSCATEGORIES');
  }
```

The usage of  the api:

```
import { ApiService } from './../api.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ProcessCategory } from './process-category';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-process-category',
  templateUrl: './process-category.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./process-category.component.css']
})
export class ProcessCategoryComponent implements OnInit {

  processCategories = [];

  constructor(private api: ApiService) {
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fillProcessCategories();
    this.printAfterRequest();
  }

  fillProcessCategories() {
    this.api.getAllProcessCategories().subscribe(data => {
      this.processCategories = data['entities'];
      console.log(this.processCategories);
    });
  }

  printAfterRequest() {
    for (const category of this.processCategories) {
          console.log(category);
    }
  }
}
```

Iknow that it is, because I want to get the result before the httpRequest is finished. So what is the best way to perform a get request in angular 4, which returns a JSON and than parse this JSON and map it to a class for use in my component?

Comment: I suggest you read a bit about how observables and asynchronous calls work. Right now the `printAfterRequest` method is going to happen before the `fillProcessCategories` has a chance to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly tweak your API method to

```
return this.http.get(this.apiURL+ 'typeOne=PROCESSCATEGORIES&typeTwo=PROCESSCATEGORIES')
                .map(res => {
                    return res.json();
                })
                .catch(this.handleError);
```

Then move `printAfterRequest` to subscribe callback

```
fillProcessCategories() {
    this.api.getAllProcessCategories().subscribe(data => {
      this.processCategories = data['entities'];
      this.printAfterRequest();
      console.log(this.processCategories);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Dear Vitalii,Since they changed to Angular 4.3 the .json map is no longer needed(also not available) since json is now default returned as an object. And still my processCategories is only filled within the callback and is no where to be  found after.

Comment: Have you tried to bind them to the template? They should be available after async call is completed. in ngOnInit() they will not be available immediately because async request take time to complete and load.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers and help. I does get the value when i template it. So now my question is , am I working correctly this way or is there a better way to get request and handle them in the component

Comment: Yes, you're on the right way. But I suggest to have separate service for each API controller prefix. , e.g. users-api.service for all /Users calls. I also have api-base.service which contains generic error handling and getUrl method that return baseApiUrl + {API_PATH}

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and tips